Understanding man pages: why is `iwd` not a command? (arch linux)
I am installing arch linux, and things are mostly going smoothly, including running iwctl from live USB. However:
When I installed arch and rebooted from disk, and tried to run iwctl again, it said: "waiting for deamon IWD".
when I called the command iwd, I got the error command not found. Yet, calling man iwd gave me a perfectly fine manual entry for iwd, with the SYNOPSIS: iwd [options]. Including the options: --version, and --help.
This suggests that iwd is a command line program, and yet it isn't found as I said earlier.
What solved my problem was instead calling systemctl start iwd. (so to be clear, my actual problem is already solved).
I'm just trying to understand why this happened: why did my bash shell not find iwd, and yet systemctl did? is iwd not actually a bash command, despite the man pages suggesting it? How could I have known this? Is it a mistake?

iwd is usually installed in /usr/libexec, which isn’t on most users’ PATH (and shouldn’t be). As a result, your shell can’t find it on its own.
iwd also ships a service definition, which is why systemctl knows about it — it doesn’t care about “commands” (whatever form they may take), it cares about services.
There might be circumstances in which it would be useful to run iwd directly, but I imagine they are unusual enough that not having iwd in a bin or sbin doesn’t cause problems most of the time.
